# PubSubHubbub notifications delay

Tags: notifications, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've recently implemented PubSubHubbub in one of my apps which subscribes to multiple Youtube channels for receiving notifications.

Unfortunately ever since I've started using it there has always been a rather long delay between a video being uploaded and my server receiving the notification.

From analyzing the notifications that I am getting it would appear that I am only getting the notifications when a video is "updated" but not "published", for example:

```
<published>2017-07-03T14:00:08+00:00</published>
<updated>2017-07-03T16:22:36.514463723+00:00</updated>
```

This is from the latest video notification I received, my server received it at almost exactly 2017-07-03 16:22:36 yet the video was actually uploaded more than 2 hours previous (and was visible on their channel). 
Is this an issue with the hub or is there potentially something missing from my implementation?

Thanks in advance